# Why is this shell command always returning 1?

Tags: bash, shell, ping

Here is a shell puzzle I can't answer (bash).

This returns exit code 1:

```
ping $HOSTNAME -c2 -W2 2&>1 > /dev/null
```

This returns the correct exit code every time (2, 1 or 0).

```
ping $HOSTNAME -c2 -W2
```

Why is the first one always returning 1? I'm just trying to hide/throwaway all the output of the ping command.

Comment: Because you meant to write "2>&1"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the order should be adjusted to:

```
ping "$myHost" -c2 -W2 > /dev/null 2>&1; echo $?
0
```

Answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119648/redirecting-to-dev-null). Essentially, the first part `> /dev/null` sends stdOut to /dev/null, then you re-route stdErr to stdOut.